# skip tagging while maven release

Tags: maven, svn, maven-release-plugin

How can I stop maven release from tagging? I tried add remoteTagging argument according to maven document http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#remoteTagging, here is my maven goal `-DremoteTagging=false release:prepare`. but this dose not work, release still commit tag folder to svn. 

 The reason I want to skip tag is because the tag folder it committed contains all the old tags, 
generating a tag structure like this:

```
+-- projectA-version1.2
|   +-- tags
|       +-- projectA-version1.1 
+-- projectA-version1.1
|   +-- tags
```

since I got more than two version, this took huge space in svn and my local workspace, how can I stop release tagging or prevent tag folder to nest every previous version?

Comment: If you getting above structure based on your tagging your configuration seemed to be wrong..furthermore the space in SVN is not huge cause tagging is a so called cheap copy which means it is a defined amount of space (ca. 1 KiB) per tag...The local workspace is not influenced by that cause you usually do not checkout tags folders ?

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for the help. you are right! after some days research svn configuration, I figure out that this is all because I didn't follow the trunk tags branches structure, instead I put tags folder and contents of trunk in the same level, that's why I got tags folder in my check out contents, hence cause the strange tags structure.